# CW decomposition of 2-torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What is the attaching map from $X_2$ to $X_3$? I know a $2$-cell is being attached, but I am unable to imagine how this is coming about.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you take the finished torus and a knife, and cut along $X_1$ you get a cylinder. If you also cut along $X_2$, you get a rectangle. This rectangle is $X_3$, with the obvious attaching map of "one round around the edge of the rectangle".

In the uncut torus, this map goes around $X_1$, then around $X_2$, then the other way around $X_1$, then the other way around $X_2$.

Comment: Ok thinking about it as a rectangular piece does help in understanding how the attaching works. Thanks.